# Error during maven/ant build: "[java] Timestamp response not valid"

Tags: java, ant, build, maven

My maven build started failing randomly, and it got the following error which I cannot make sense of, and googling it doesn't give me anything useful:

```
[echo] Creating a full package...
[java] Timestamp response not valid
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] BUILD ERROR
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Failed to execute: Executing Ant script: /airtest.build.xml [package-admin-air]: Failed to execute.
Java returned: 10
[exec] [DEBUG] Trace
[exec] org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute: Executing Ant script: /airtest.build.xml [package-admin-air]: Failed to execute.
[exec]     at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoals(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:719)
[exec]     at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoalWithLifecycle(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:556)
[exec]     at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoal(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:535)
[exec]     at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoalAndHandleFailures(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:387)
[exec]     at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeTaskSegments(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:348)
[exec]     at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.execute(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:180)
[exec]     at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:328)
[exec]     at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:138)
[exec]     at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:362)
[exec]     at org.apache.maven.cli.compat.CompatibleMain.main(CompatibleMain.java:60)
[exec]     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
[exec]     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
[exec]     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
[exec]     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
[exec]     at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:315)
[exec]     at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:255)
[exec]     at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:430)
[exec]     at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:375)
[exec] Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: Failed to execute: Executing Ant script: /airtest.build.xml [package-admin-air]: Failed to execute.
[exec]     at org.apache.maven.script.ant.AntMojoWrapper.execute(AntMojoWrapper.java:56)
[exec]     at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultPluginManager.java:490)
[exec]     at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoals(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:694)
[exec]     ... 17 more
[exec] Caused by: org.codehaus.plexus.component.factory.ant.AntComponentExecutionException: Executing Ant script: /airtest.build.xml [package-admin-air]: Failed to execute.
[exec]     at org.codehaus.plexus.component.factory.ant.AntScriptInvoker.invoke(AntScriptInvoker.java:227)
[exec]     at org.apache.maven.script.ant.AntMojoWrapper.execute(AntMojoWrapper.java:52)
[exec]     ... 19 more
[exec] Caused by: C:\Users\dev\plexus-ant-component4263631821803364095.build.xml:445: Java returned: 10
[exec]     at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Java.execute(Java.java:87)
[exec]     at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:275)
[exec]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:364)
[exec]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:341)
[exec]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:369)
[exec]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1216)
[exec]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTarget(Project.java:1185)
[exec]     at org.codehaus.plexus.component.factory.ant.AntScriptInvoker.invoke(AntScriptInvoker.java:222)
```

This is a random error that pops up in various point during the build process, and sometimes the build will succeed and then the next one will fail again. This is really weird, does anyone seen this before? I'm using maven 2.2.1

BTW, the error return code 10 in windows mean "Environment is invalid.

Comment: You're using Maven... to call an Ant script which is very likely faulty here (I'm pretty sure the message comes from the Ant script). Please update your question accordingly and maybe add relevant parts of your Ant script).

Comment: i checked the script, but it doesn't seem to have errors. In fact, it hasn't been changed, and the build still sparkling succeed.

Comment: My point is that the error message of the title of your question is AFAIK not part of Maven, it seems to be kinda custom (and I believe it comes from your Ant build script).

Comment: Did you update your JDK recently?

Answer (score 0):

I'm running into the same problem, which just started about an hour ago here too. We're using TeamCity. I was able to build fine in ant from eclipse, so not sure what the difference is that's going on.

[java] Timestamp response not valid

Comment: No JDK update, but the error has gone away for me. My guess is that adt communicates with a server for one reason or another, and that server was down.

Answer (score 0):

Also seeing similar behavior. "Getting [exec] Timestamp response not valid" response from our Hudson server. Just started happening randomly.

Could be a time stamp service issue?

Comment: Could this be related to a JDK udpate? Are you using Ant or Maven?

Comment: Our error went away aswell, around 630pm EST to be exact. Agree with da.